# How to Animate List Reordering in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have a list of items that's bound to an array via an Observable.  My application has an action effect where one of those items in the list gets a property change thus causing it to be reordered to the end of the array (currently implemented in code with a fullblown .sort() on the array).

What I would like is to be able to actually make it look like the item in the visual list animates from its starting position (in the array) to its new position (at the end of the list) by moving from location X to location Y.

Is this possible with Angular animations?  I am more than willing to stop using Array.sort() and just programmatically move the item via a splice() call.

Comment: This references angular 1, but it might get this conversation rolling in the right direction. I'm actually really interested to see what the result of this question is myself.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523531/list-reorder-animation-with-angularjs

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is still relevant. But this plugin should do the trick with some configuration.

https://isotope.metafizzy.co/