# Animate orderBy list values in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, jquery-animate

I've found some cool answers for animating a list getting ordered in Angular:
[How can I animate sorting a list with orderBy using ng-repeat with ng-animate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431136/angularjs-how-can-i-animate-sorting-a-list-with-orderby-using-ng-repeat-with-n)

However, these answers only order the data by reverse/unreverse or random. I've tried to apply the same principle to order data by the values.

HTML:

```
<div id="division" ng-style="{height: (division.length * 42) + 'px'}">
  <div class="divisionRow" ng-repeat="player in division" ng-style="{top: (player.order * 42) + 'px'}">
    <div>Name: {{player.name}}</div>
    <div>Number: {{player.number}}</div>
    <div>Points: {{player.points}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
//division object
  $scope.division = [
    { name: "Jim", number: 1, points: 10 },
    { name: "Paul", number: 2, points: 19 },
    { name: "Amy", number: 3,points: 3 },
    { name: "Greg", number: 4,points: 6 },
    { name: "Rob", number: 5,points: 20 }
  ];

  //sort order
  $scope.sortBy = function(sortValue){
    if (sortValue == "number") $scope.division.sort(compareNumber);
    if (sortValue == "points") $scope.division.sort(comparePoints);
    angular.forEach($scope.division, function(player, key){ player.order = key; });
  }

  //number compare functions
  function compareNumber(a,b){
    if (a.number < b.number) return -1;
    if (a.number > b.number) return 1;
    return 0;                  
  }

  //points compare function
  function comparePoints(a,b) {
    if (a.points < b.points) return 1;
    if (a.points > b.points) return -1;
    if (a.number < b.number) return -1;
    if (a.number > b.number) return 1;
    return 0;
  }
```

CSS:

```
#division { position: relative; }

.divisionRow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 42px;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: top 0.5s ease-out;}

.divisionRow div { 
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px; }
```

Here's a working jsBin:
http://jsbin.com/cebibejoho/1/

I can't seem to get the animation working consistently. When sorting, some of the rows just jump into place rather than animate. I think this is something to do with when the player.order value is updated and the style of that row changes in the HTML. It's not applying the CSS transition when that happens but I don't understand why not.

Comment: do you want to animate only at the start. i.e at the first click.. or on each click it should animate to new position

Comment: Yes every time the user re-sorts the list, it should animate the rows into their new positions. I want the animation achieved in the answer I linked to, but sorting by specific fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see, what angular ng-repeat does,

1. the html nodes are overwritten according to changes in the object used in ng-repeat. that means, the order of the elements in the dom tree is itself changed.
2. Animation is something which should not change the order of the elements internally but only change the position of the element.
3. So in-order to make it an animation effect, don't sort the object(`division` in your case) on click. instead make it move around for that you need to create your own directive for defining the animation for the list.

by sorting the object itself, you will not be able to animate it.

Comment: But the animation happens when the `player.order` number is updated, which in turn updates the "top" `ng-style` in the HTML (of course the CSS transition does the smooth change). So how come it understands to move the objects, but the CSS transition doesn't work?

Comment: because initially there is an order defined which can be animated , in your code it does. for subsequent changes in your object, `ng-repeat` would not help you, as it will just change the `dom` objects created, so they will be different than what you had initially, so you would not be able to  animate them.

Comment: OK I think I understand. I'll try changing putting the information in a new array and applying values for restyling from that, rather than changing the original object.

Comment: Yes.. U understood.. Good luck :)

Comment: Unfortunately I still can't get this working. Would you be able to edit my jsBin example to show a solution?

Comment: Which method worked coop.. Can you add the link to the solution if possible.. That would be useful to future readers..