# animating list with ng-repeat - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

I am using angularjs directive ng-repeat.

Item 1

Item 2

Item 3

Item 4

Item 5

I want an animation which changes the position of each list after some interval

eg.

Item 5

Item 1

Item 2

Item 3

Item 4

Next value should be like this after some time interval

Item 4

Item 5

Item 1

Item 2

Item 3

and it goes on

Kindly help

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431136/how-can-i-animate-sorting-a-list-with-orderby-using-ng-repeat-with-ng-animate

Comment: list is rearranged in random order. I want change of position one by one that too on page load and not on any event