# ngRepeat animations not working on all elements

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I would like to build a simple list with angular, where some items are placed to the top of the list by animating their absolute top position.

So I built a simple view:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="person in list | orderBy: sort"
  ng-style="{top: $index * 20 + 'px'}">
    <span>{{person.name}}</span>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="person.checked"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Where list is an array of objects, and sort is a simple sorting function:

```
$scope.sort = function(person) {
  var comparisonString = '';
  if(person.checked) {
    comparisonString += '0';
  }
  comparisonString += person.name;
  return comparisonString;
};
```

And gave it some simple styling:

```
ul {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
}
ul li {
  position:absolute;
  transition: top 1s linear;
}
```

However, if I click on one of the checkboxes, the element immediately moves to the top, without the 1s animation. And if I uncheck an element, then the ones below it immediately occupy the space above, again, without animating. This probably has something to do with the fact that I am defining styles via the ngStyle directive, however I can't figure out a way to deal with this without ngStyle.

An example of this situation is in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/W8JyblLaDQk5nWUVKH9A?p=preview).

I'd be really thankful if someone could help me!

Answer (score 0):

HEre's an example of what I can read that you are trying to do:

```
function rearrange(){
            $('.item').each(function(idx, el){
                var $el = $(el);                
                var newTop = idx * $config.OFFSET_Y;

                if (newTop != parseInt($el.css('top'))) {
                    $el.css({
                        'top': newTop
                    })
                    .one('webkitTransitionEnd', function (evt){
                        $(evt.target).removeClass('moving');
                    })
                    .addClass('moving');    
                }

            });
```

In this example, the movements are automated in the scope in the backend.  I figure you could pull them apart and use them for each item in the list.

source:  http://codepen.io/daleyjem/pen/xbZYpY

Comment: I am aware of this example, however I am reluctant to define a brand new directive for what seems to be (or at least seems that it should be) already supported by native angular directives.

Comment: ok.  How about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431136/how-can-i-animate-sorting-a-list-with-orderby-using-ng-repeat-with-ng-animate

Comment: This one is also very nice, but it doesn't leverage the orderBy filter as in my example. This could be ok, but I feel that using presentation properties to determine order of a list is an approach that can come back to bite me.

I suppose the answer is that I should avoid animating like this and find another design solution. However, it would still be interesting to find out why exactly this didn't work.