# Is there a bug in ng-repeat orderBy while using css animations?

Tags: angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-repeat

Summary:
When adding `orderBy` to my animated `ng-repeat`, some of the animations are breaking.
Am i doing something wrong?

Details:
After taking the lovely animations here from here:
[How can I animate sorting a list with orderBy using ng-repeat with ng-animate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431136/how-can-i-animate-sorting-a-list-with-orderby-using-ng-repeat-with-ng-animate)

I found out that adding `| orderBy: 'order'` ruins my animation, especially those which should be animated going up.

As far as i understand, orderBy creates an inside order using the ng-repeat tag. When i used `limitTo`, i had to use the `orderBy` because otherwise i simply don't get my first items first.
Since the inside order is practically ignored as i use  `position: absolute;` in my css, i have expected it to work well.

I've created two Fiddles trying to prove my point:
Here is the working fiddle. when i click on reverse=false, it re-organizes the rows. Then clicking moveUp, moves the 5th row to the second one with animation, which is great.
http://jsfiddle.net/yoni6/vrtz3Lz3/

Then, when i add `| orderBy: 'order'`, which is needed for my real big list, the same animation breaks up.
http://jsfiddle.net/yoni6/6Latu44y/2/

Please help me figuring out whether it is a bug or im doing something wrong :)

Comment: None of the Fiddles is using `orderBy`.

Comment: really? im new to using fiddle, i hope everyone can see what i see.  the second link has the html line:     <li ng-repeat="item in myList | **orderBy**: 'order'" ng-style="{top: ((item.order * 20) + 'px')}">{{$index}} - {{item.order}}. {{item.text}}</li>

Comment: The second one contains `orderBy` now.

Comment: oh, u r right, i fixed it shortly after posting and u have probably seen it before the fix.