# Can I animate the sorting of an angular ng-repeat that uses orderBy?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, animation

I would like to animate the sorting of ng-repeat's orderBy to do something similar to this (using the sorting buttons):

http://tristanguigue.github.io/angular-dynamic-layout/

or this:
[How can I animate sorting a list with orderBy using ng-repeat with ng-animate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431136/how-can-i-animate-sorting-a-list-with-orderby-using-ng-repeat-with-ng-animate)

The problem with both of these is that I have many orders and filters that change dynamically. The first would require a complete rewrite of my code, while the second seems like it will only really work with one type of ordering.

Here is my html of ng-repeat so you can see what I mean:

```
<span class="card" ng-repeat="acqui in acquis | orderBy:order:reverse | fieldFilter: fieldFilter | countryFilter: countryFilter | filter: undisclosedFilter | filter:searchText | limitTo: quantity">
    <card-info class="card move-items-animation" acqui="acqui"</card-info>
</span>
```

And my order method:

```
$scope.order = 'date';
$scope.reverse = true;
var current = $scope.order;
$scope.updateOrder = function(order) {
    console.log(order);
    if(current === order) {
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    } else if($scope.reverse) {
        $scope.reverse = false;
        $scope.order = order;
        current = order;
    } else {
        $scope.order = order;
        current = order;
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in my html I have buttons whose ng-click call updateOrder(String) to change what field ng-repeat orders everything by. Similar idea with the filters.

Is there something I can do to easily animate the sorting? Possibly an external lib? The closest thing I have seen is stopping ng-repeat from reloading my objects to the DOM and doing so myself in the correct order while animating, but that seems overly complex for something like this.

Comment: Have you read that ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431136/how-can-i-animate-sorting-a-list-with-orderby-using-ng-repeat-with-ng-animate

Comment: Yes, it's the second link in my post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I animate sorting a list with orderBy using ng-repeat with ng-animate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431136/how-can-i-animate-sorting-a-list-with-orderby-using-ng-repeat-with-ng-animate)